# Как обратится к дочеренему объекту по позиции в иерархии? C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Заранее каждому спасибо за потраченное время <3 Так вот, Есть у меня основной объект например "Forest"
и у него около 10 дочерних объектов "Tree" я хочу через скрипт в "Лесу" обратиться к каждому "Дереву" и с ним что-то сделать (Либо к отдельному дереву, по случаю надобности). Можно ли как то обратиться к дочернему по положению в иерархии по типу первое дерево в иерархии имеет свой айди, что бы можно было через циклы проводить манипуляции. Может есть что то проще или другой способ

Comment: Yaroslav Вот то что я хотел узнать, так как я новичёк. Вот что огорчило что твоя религия не даёт написать хоть что-то без упрека. Просто сказать что порядок массива тот же что и в иерархии и всё (В вопросе всё ясно и можно было без твоей религии, друг). И не было никакого основания нового индекса в моём вопросе, сам придумал, сам оскорбил вымышленную религию, КРАСАВА и спасибо

Comment: Никакого перехода на личности, просто скупая оценка. Если нужна помощь, про самомнение и эго нужно забыть. Квалифицированная критика, это и есть помощь, причем основная, а не вот эта сыска. Не способе ее принять, твоя половая драма. Хочешь ультра тактичных замечаний не задевающих твою гордость, нанимай репитетора за деньги, не будет повода огорчаться в интернетах. На тебя потратили время, ты еще и жалуешься... и кто тут бяка?

Comment: Yaroslav как скажешь <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unity Scripting API: Transform](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html)

Через Find(), GetChild() и childCount можешь найти объекты и перебирать их в цикле. Там и другие интересные методы есть. И пример есть, как перебрать все дочерние объекты.